# How to validate the XML is well formed or not in teradata

Tags: teradata

I have a employee table. Employee details column is XML but stored as varchar type. I need to validate whether XML is well formed or not.

Note : tried isdocument() but facing Below error - 
the owner expression of the udm invocation is not a udf.

Query :
Select employee_xml.isdocument() from employee;

Tried both cast and new XML () is not working for isDocument().

Comment: `Select cast(employee_xml as xml).isdocument() from employee;`

Comment: @dnoeth, I've tried this before. I don't know what is considered a valid xml document.   This simple but valid bit of XML returns 0 :`<a name = "foo"> <b name = "bar"</b> </a>`.

Comment: @Andrew Well, it checks if XML is *well-formed*, whatever that means. In fact I don't care as I try to avoid XML :-)

Comment: Probably just a typo, but I don't think that's valid. Begin/end tags need to be paired `<a name = "foo"> <b name = "bar"> </b> </a>`. I don't know why, but with a CAST as XML, isdocument() always seems to return 0. And if you try `(NEW XML(employee_xml)).isdocument()` you get 1 if it's valid but error 7458 if it's not :-(

Comment: Boggle...so explicitly casting it as xml doesn't work, but new xml does.  I can live with that :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How to make a XML as well formed. For example  Complete XML : <a><b>John<|b><a>
Sometime I will receive employee_xml in half baked like below. <a><b>john

Comment: Are you asking how to determine if you have valid XML, or how to fix it if you don't?  Fred's comment should allow to to determine if you have "well formed" XML.  If you are asking about fixing bad XML, that needs to happen at the source.

Comment: I need both functionality. First I need to check whether XML is well formed or not. I need to fix that